# Is Android Open Source Project (AOSP) already inside android SDK

Tags: android, android-source

I was trying to look at the sources of some AOSP classes like: 
"android.com.android.server.am.DumpHeapProvider" (i then found the source inside this repository and looked at it online: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/services/core/java/com/android/server/am/DumpHeapProvider.java), so I tryed to import the class inside a new project created with AndroidStudio and I immediately noticed that AndroidStudio didn't found the class...

So I was wondering if AOSP classes and its packages are somehow "external" things that should be downloaded and imported in you project before they can be used, just like a library.

It sounds weird because searching for AOSP gets me to a sentence which states that AOSP is composed by android OS and middleware, so I was expecting its libraries to be part of Android SDK, which I downloaded with AndroidStudio...

What is the correct way to use these AOSP classes?

Answer (score 1):

> I tryed to import the class inside a new project created with AndroidStudio and I immediately noticed that AndroidStudio didn't found the class

The vast majority of the AOSP represents code for an operating system. Very little of it is part of the Android SDK, and very little of it is usable by an app.

> I was wondering if AOSP classes and its packages are somehow "external" things that should be downloaded and imported in you project before they can be used, just like a library.

They are used to build an operating system.

> What is the correct way to use these AOSP classes?

Build an operating system, such as Android.

Comment: So it's very unlike to see another android apk using these classes? And, in that case, what should I expect to see in the apk? External packages representing AOSP classes and imports of that classes inside the code like any other library?

Comment: @AlessioMartorana: "it's very unlike to see another android apk using these classes?" -- sorry, I do not know what you mean. "what should I expect to see in the apk?" -- sorry, I do not know what APK you are referring to.

Comment: FIRST QUOTE: I mean: since you said majority of AOSP classes are used to build an operative system, is unlike to see AOSP classes used by a "standard" android apk which already runs on Android OS. SECOND QUOTE: In the case of an apk using AOSP classes, opening the apk final package, what must I expect to see? Packages with the AOSP classes inside it and, supposing to decompile the source, imports for the AOSP classes?

Comment: @AlessioMartorana: "In the case of an apk using AOSP classes" -- this does not exist in general. A developer is welcome to grab random files from random places, like the AOSP, and try using them. Often, they will not work, as they depend on other things that the app lacks. If they do work, they would be indistinguishable from other code in that APK. "opening the apk final package, what must I expect to see?" -- that depends on a lot of things, such as whether the developer who wrote the APK used ProGuard, DexGuard, or other obfuscation tools.